Migration of data from OraclDB to PostgreSQL without Golden Gate
Do you have any ideas of data migration from OracleDB to PostgreSQL without Golden Gate?
I live in Russia and I want to create analogue of Golden Gate.
Analogue should transfer data from OracleDB to PostgreSQL
I thought and tried to use kafka topics to write and read from them, but this way is so bad.
I want to know thoughts of community because Im stumped.
Maybe you, guys can give me some ideas.

This will almost certainly be closed because there is no clear question. It sounds like you might prefer a discussion board / mailing list. If you are on a PostgreSQL list make sure to explain what "Golden Gate" is - I've never heard of it.

Ok,thank you. man
